# References for converting old units to new units

Tags: units, measurement

I am currently looking for references on books that deal with the conversion of old units to new units.

I am particularly interested in books that actually have tables of conversion because I need to convert some units in my research.

I would be grateful for any recommendations that you can provide.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Sincerely,
Lucas N.

Comment: **I need to convert some units in my research** You can't just ask Google ??  I say "convert 5 miles to kilometers" and it tells me "8.04672"   For fun, try "convert 5 furlongs per fortnight to kilometers per hour"

Comment: It doesn't help. My units are too old, google doesn't understand. Moreover, I'm writing a paper, so I would like to cite the source from my conversion (and citing websites is uninteresting).

Comment: Please precise which units you need to convert

Comment: See [List of obsolete units of measurement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_obsolete_units_of_measurement)